# How can you use Google Apps Script to get the location of inline images in a Google Doc?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

Google Apps Script, through the Text method  [getTextAttributeIndices()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#getTextAttributeIndices()) allows the programmatic acquisition of the set of text indices at which text formatting changes. The text formatting changes allows the user to get the location of characters in bold, italics etc. However it does not appear to support locating the position of inline images. Is there any way to get the locations of inline images without any temporary fixes or workarounds ? I am looking for a functionality similar to the code below that I used to find the starting location of chars in bold:

```
function get_bold(text_obj){
var idc = text_obj.getTextAttributeIndices(); // gets text indices where formatting changes
for (var i in idc){ 
 if(text_obj.isBold(idc[i]){   
   Logger.log(idc[i]);
  }
 } 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible, since an inline image is not a partial element (unlike a bolded part of text).